# Supersized: playToggle

Tags: jquery, supersized

I am using the Supersized background slideshow:

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

with the following code to pause the Slideshow while loading a modal box.

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
 $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
    api.playToggle();
  });
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="btnContainer">
<a id="slideInfo" href="#">More Info</a>
</div>
```

I am able to pause the slideshow. However, when I close the modal box the Slideshow won't play back again (it stays paused).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the test site:

http://clientes.ktulumedia.com/peppophotography.com

And the relevant code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function($) {
 $('#slideInfoplay').click(function() {
 api.playToggle();
 });
 });


 $(function($) {
 $('#sb-nav-close').click(function() {
 api.playToggle();
 });
 });

 </script>
```

Click where it says "test". I am able to open the modal box and pause the slideshow. However, when I close the modal box, I am unable to restart the slideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [plugin usage](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#api-playtoggle) is true but your [jQuery document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method is wrong.

```
$(function() {//you shouldnt use '$' inside function()
 $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
    api.playToggle();
  });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
    api.playToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment barlasapaydin. I've made the necessary changes. However, I think there's some extra code missing in order to play the slideshow once it's paused for the first time.

Comment: than you should show us your work. if i could inspect your code, i'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @barlaspaydin! Here's the site I am working on: http://clientes.ktulumedia.com/peppophotography.com

Comment: lol its just working fine on my computer, chrome. what is your opareting system and browser?

Comment: i pressed pause, its just resetts the bar, but i when i press play again. it will countunie from beggining without any bug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14076/discussion-between-johann-and-barlasapaydin)